Find Largest free Rectangle in Matrix Algorithm
I have a N*M sized Rectangle (where N,M can be up to 10000 (min. of 1)) I will call the Map,
and multiple Rectangles in a List<Rectangle> I will call Islands, with some intersecting with the Map.
I would now like to find any Rectangle with the largest area within the Map.
With a Map up to a size of 100'000'000 I believe checking each Location is too slow and I believe there has to be a smart algorithm I can't think of.
I have tried it with each Tile, but it can be a little slow, especially with multiple iterations.
I am bad at explaining, so maybe some can work better with the Method name
public Rectangle LargestFreeRectangle(Rectangle occupiedRectangles)

This sounds like a [math.se] question, not a programming problem yet? Are you looking for "how do I even do this" or do you know how to do this, and you need help implementing it?  Also, as a programming question: what actual data are you working with (bitmaps? a collection of islands? something else?) Because that makes a huge difference in what your options are.

Could you edit your question and add a concrete example input initialised in (pseudo) code, and the expected output for it?

There is no way to just ignore some rectangles. You'll at least need to check for each of them something, unless you found a rectangle that completely encompasses the map. That's the only case where you can stop looking further.

"to find any Rectangle with the largest area within the Map"  What does this mean?  Best guess: the largest area rectangular shape that contains no 'islands'.  You need to clarify this.  Suggestion: post a small example showing the expected result.

For this kind of problem, quad trees are often a life safer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree
When you add the first island, you will need to update the quad tree so it represents the remaining free space

Each time you add another island, break up the quad tree as required.
When you have added all the islands, iterate over the quad tree to find the largest free space.
Assumptions:

You want the largest area rectangular shape that contains no 'islands'.

No island overlaps another and all islands are inside the big rectanle. ( with a bit of care you can handle this wrinkle, but assuming this makes things simpler


For an entertaining introduction to quad trees check out the billion dollar code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Billion_Dollar_Code

Difficult to exactly guess what you are trying to do.
My thought is to pre-sort the Islands by size largest to smallest.
Iterate over this list of sorted Islands checking if they are in your desired area, then as soon as you find one, it is by definition the largest and you can stop searching.

That second sentence is doing too much heavy lifting: unless you can unpack how one would (efficiently) get that list of islands this should have been a comment, not an answer.
